# Strange Polygon Shape Rendering in ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.22

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing, arcgis-web-appbuilder

When I upload a shapefile using the existing WAB Geoprocessing widget Shapefile uploader. Below is the screenshot. What could be the cause of the problem?
The image below was supposed to show the shape of Kenya. The issue happens in other polygons too. 
[image]

Comment: Perhaps run the shapefile through the Check Geometry tool, and optionally the Repair Geometry tool. Do the polygons look fine when you view the shapefile directly in ArcMap or Pro?

Comment: Yes, they are fine. Now it is fixed. It was spatial reference issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the problem was the spatial reference for the Shapefile uploader (wkid: 4326) was different from the map spatial reference (wkid: 102100). When I changed it, it started to render the shapes correctly.